# PHPStan with array shape doc

Tags: php, phpstan

I have an array like below:

```
array [
    "total" => 0,
    "seed" => 0,
    "stringKey1" => array<string, string>,
    "stringKey2" => array<string, string>,
    ...
    "stringKeyN" => array<string, string>
]
```

I have question about how to use Phpstan to document above array shape.
the "stringKey"s are produced in run time.

I just donot know how to write down "stringKey" part of PHPStan document

Comment: Is `array<string, int|array<string, string>>` not sufficient?